# How I can turn this useless information off in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How I can turn this useless information off in Visual Studio Code?
It just annoys me

That was useless!

[image: It just annoys me]

[image: It just annoys me]

Answer (score 0):

I just found the way to delay this infobox by hover in settings and set it from 10 milliseconds to 3000 milliseconds.

Comment: it would help to also mention the setting you changed

Comment: there is also a `Hover Enable` setting

Comment: Yeh, I changed the Hover delay.